# Avoid "Repairing cluster" in GKE by pre-specifying master size?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I have an auto-scaling node pool on a GKE cluster, and when it gets large the whole cluster goes into "Repairing cluster" mode.  At that time, I've seen my workloads disappear or get kicked out and fall into status "Does not have minimum availability".

Is there anyway to create the cluster in advance, perhaps pre-specifying some size parameter, to avoid this?

Comment: What GKE version are you using? How did you create your cluster, did create it using default settings? Did you changed `CPU` or `Memory` resources? Are you using any `HPA` or `CA`? Could you provide more details for reproducing this issue? Did you check [gke troubleshooting docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#does_not_have_minimum_availability) ? Did you consider to create more nodepools with different machine type (for example e2-standard-8 (8 vCPU, 32 GB memory))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to achieve this.   The suggestion from Google is to use a regional cluster, which can have multiple replicas of the control plane.  During a master resizing event, at least one replica should remain available at all times.

See [this response](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/192000009#comment2) to an issue filed with GKE.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to downvote this answer, but it is wrong. From GCP's official [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/types-of-clusters#availability): "Zonal clusters have a single control plane in a single zone"

Comment: Thanks for the correction.  Updated to suggest regional cluster.

Answer (score 0):

[Auto-repairing nodes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-repair)

> GKE's node auto-repair feature helps you keep the nodes in your cluster in a healthy, running state. When enabled, GKE makes periodic checks on the health state of each node in your cluster. If a node fails consecutive health checks over an extended time period, GKE initiates a repair process for that node.

When one of your node will report status different than `ready` like:

- A node reports a `NotReady` status on consecutive checks over the given time threshold (approximately 10 minutes).
- A node does not report any status at all over the given time threshold (approximately 10 minutes).
- A node's boot disk is out of disk space for an extended time period (approximately 30 minutes).

[GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine) will start `auto-repairing`. Depending on the number of nodes and the load, this may take different amounts of time.

[Does not have minimum availability](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#does_not_have_minimum_availability)
When this issue occurs it mean that in the current time cluster don't have enough resources to run all pods.

> If a node has adequate resources but you still see the Does not have minimum availability message, check the Pod's status. If the status is SchedulingDisabled or Cordoned status, the node cannot schedule new Pods. You can check the status of a node using Cloud Console or the kubectl command-line tool.

As per troubleshooting guide, you should check `nodes` status

```
$ kubectl get nodes
```

And eventually `uncordon` it.

```
$ kubectl uncordon node-name
```

Possible reasons, why you got `Does not have minimum availability` information and solution.

- The nodes are still being repaired *>>>* As you mentioned `when it gets large`, sometimes you just need longer to repair nodes.
- Readiness probe failure / Liveliness probe failure **>>>** check application, your cluster details.
- There might be situation that `Google Cloud` does not have enough resource available in the specific `Region`/`Zone` that you are trying to launch. **>>>** You can choose different `Region`/`Zone`

Regarding your question, **Is there anyway to create the cluster in advance, perhaps pre-specifying some size parameter, to avoid this?**

You can [Reserve resources](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/consuming-reservations). For more details, please check [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources).

Comment: Why copy paste documentation without an explicit answer?